# Interpolation code in Google Earth Engine

Tags: time-series, interpolation, google-earth-engine

I'm looking for interpolation code for time series in Google Earth Engine, to convert NDVI Sentinel 2 data to daily data. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not as straightforward as a simple interpolation, but you can achieve this with the CCDC temporal segmentation algorithm. It models the seasonal behavior based on harmonic models. You can find the docs here:
https://gee-ccdc-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/background.html

If you follow the tutorials you should get a good overview of how it works though.

Good luck!